# SQL Server 2012 : SELECT and UPDATE in one query slow performance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am running SQL Server 2012 and this one query is killing my database performance.

My text message provider does not support scheduled text messages so I have a text message engine that picks up messages from the database and sends them at the scheduled time. I put this query together that gets the messages from the database and also changes their status so that they do not get picked up again.

The query works fine, it is just causing wait times on the CPU especially since it runs every other second. I installed a database performance software and it said this query accounts for 92% of instance execution time. The software also said that every single execution is doing 347,267 Logical Reads.

Any ideas on how to make this perform better?

Should I maybe select into a temporary table and update those results before returning them?

Here is the current query:

```
    UPDATE TOP (30) dbo.Outgoing
    SET Status = 2
    OUTPUT INSERTED.OutgoingID, INSERTED.[Message], n.PhoneNumber, c.OptInStatus
    FROM dbo.Outgoing o
    JOIN Numbers n on n.NumberID = o.NumberID
    LEFT JOIN Contacts c on c.ContactID = o.ContactID
    WHERE Scheduled <= GETUTCDATE() AND SmsId IS NULL AND Status = 1
```

Here is the execution plan
[image: ExecutionPlan]

There are three tables involved in this query: Outgoing, Numbers, & Contacts

Outgoing is the main table that this query deals with. There are only two indexes right now, a clustered primary key index on OutgoingID [PK, bigint, not null] and a non-clustered, non-unique index on SmsId [varchar(255), null] which is an identifier sent back from our text message provider once the messages are successfully received in their system. The Status column is just an integer column that relates to a few different statuses (Scheduled, Queued, Sent, Failed, Etc)

Numbers is just a simple table where we store unique cell phone numbers, some different formats of that number, and some basic information identifying the customer such as First name, carrier, etc. It just has a clustered primary key index on NumberID [bigint]. The PhoneNumber column is just a varchar(15).

The Contacts table just connects the individual person (phone number) to one of our merchants and keeps up with the number's opt in status, and other information related to the customer/merchant relationship. The only columns related to this query are OptInStatus [bit, not null] and ContactID [PK, bigint, not null]

> --UPDATE--

Added a non-clustered index on the the Outgoing table with columns (Scheduled, SmsId, Status) and that seems to have brought down the execution time from 2+ second to milliseconds.  I will check in with my performance monitoring software tomorrow to see how it has improved.  Thank you everyone for the help so far!

Comment: What is the execution plan for the query?  What is the table schema here?  What indexes have you got on Numbers and Outgoing?

Comment: I'm guessing you need an index on `(Status, Scheduled)` or possibly `(Status, Scheduled, NumberID)`.

Comment: Your `TOP 30` isn't safe without an `ORDER BY`. You may not be updating the 30 records you expect to be updating if there are more than 30 which meet your criteria.

Comment: Well it rarely updates 30 records during an execution, I just want to select up to 30 records (max provider can send per second) and of those records selected update them with the new status.  I will try to get a screenshot of the execution plan and a list of indexes on those two tables.  Status & Scheduled are on the Outgoing table, NumberID is on the Numbers table. I will try adding an ORDER BY to see if it helps. Does the order of the elements in the WHERE clause make a difference?

Comment: I tried adding an ORDER BY to the end of the query but it gave me an invalid syntax error.  Where would I put the ORDER BY in this query?

Comment: Forget about ORDER BY for now... although the top result is arbitrary it probably doesn't matter if you are running this every second. If you look at your query plan, take a look at the node that says 96%. What is it doing? It's difficult to tell since in the WHERE part you did not alias the columns in your query (BAD HABIT). When you got the query plan did it suggest an index? You might benefit from a filtered index on the Scheduled column (filtered on SmsId IS NULL AND Status = 1)

Comment: slow how much slow it is?
it seems like IMAGE of estimated execution plan, can you post the Actual execution plan not IMAGE

Comment: All columns in WHERE cause are in Outgoing table. There were no index suggestions in the execution plan. I took RBarryYoung's advice and added a non-clustered index on (Status, Scheduled) and that seemed to improve the speed of the query from 2 seconds to under 1 second. So I looked at the execution plan again and it recommended I create a non-clustered index (Status, SmsId, Scheduled) so I modified my previous index to include SmsId but now it keeps saying to create that index even though it exists.

Comment: please keep in mind Index suggestions is only based of Estimated Values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As several commenters have already pointed out you need a new index on the `dbo.Outgoing` table. The server is struggling with finding the rows to update/output. This is most probably where the problem is:

```
WHERE Scheduled <= GETUTCDATE() AND SmsId IS NULL AND Status = 1
```

To improve performance you should create an index on `dbo.Outgoing` where you include these columns. This will make is easier for Sql Server to find the correct rows. It will on the other hand create some more work for the actual update though since there will be a new index that needs attention when updating.

While you're working on this, it would likely be a good idea to shorten the `SmsId` column unless you actually need it to be 255 chars long. Preferably before you create the index.

As an alternate solution you might think about having separate tables for the messages that are outgoing and those that are *outgone*. Then you can:

- insert all records from `Outgoing` to `Outgone`
- delete all records from `Outgoing`, with output clause like you are currently doing.

Make sure though that the `insert` and the `delete` operations are done in one transaction or you will soon have weird inconsistencies in the database.

Answer (score 0):

> it is just causing wait times on the CPU especially since it runs every other second.

Get rid of the `TOP 30` and run it much less often than once every other second... maybe every two or three minutes.

Comment: The provider has it's own queue that is a simple first in first out but my queue is weighted for more important messages to get priority. The provider is capable of sending 30 messages per second which is why I get 30 every other second. Not all messages are running through this queue, some are still going directly to the provider for now so I can't over-saturate their queue. Text messages are time sensitive so they need to go out ASAP, even waiting 5 seconds is unacceptable. If anything it needs to be running more often than less.

Answer (score -2):

You can enable max degree of parallelism of your sql server for faster processing